# Windows 10 not releasing Processes

Tags: windows-10, crash, process, gpu

For the past month i have been going crazy as to why my Render systems where crashing, logs looked normal, or, they didn't have any particular errors relating to the crashes.

the last week i have been searching for a temporary solution until i swap them to Linux, i was looking for a way of automating a reboot when a system froze up or crashed.

Today i noticed something though, I caught a stall just as it was happening and managed to log in remotely and kill the Software that causes this issue.

This gave me time to look around and I found this.

[image]

Normally, there will be 4 instances of this process but for some reason there is 15+, I believe it is caused by a restart the software remotely when I try to prevent a crash, but the processes are not ending as new ones open.

The program closes and the process for that program is still running.

When the program is then re-open it creates 4 new processes and the old processes are still running, every time the software is restarted

Anyone know why this is or how to prevent it?

I have changed the Compatibility mode to run for Windows 7

We are running Windows 10 Professional 64 - bit with 80gb of RAM
8 Nvidia GTX 980Tis in each box.

Comment: What command are you using to kill the software?

Comment: Remotely, it's built into our monitor software so i'm not sure as to what the exact command is, we just hit a button, sometimes i will log into the machine tho and close the application myself which is what i did today and it resulted in this.

Comment: Then it's difficult to help you. You need to look for a command that kills child processes as well as the parent processes. For example `taskkill` with the `/t` (tree) option.

Comment: How many cores (both physical and virtual) does this system have?

Comment: which AV suite do you use?

Comment: Turns out it's just hanging process IDs, they only appear after a hard Reboot, if the computer is restarted properly they disappear, i've experienced this a few times with License Servers after they crash.